# Translucent and custom image in Navigation Bar iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

In iOS 6 i used this method

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
// Drawing code
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nav_bar.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

But when i use this in iOS 7 it only covers the leaving the status bar empty, i already tried using a bigger image, it doesnt work.

But most importantly i want to use the translucent option in the navigation bar, is it compatible translucid and having a custom image in the nav bar?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work good enough. If I were you, I would try to play around with your image's alpha, however from what I've seen, ios7 design should be as light as possible (so no custom flashy graphics in nav bars)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly (apologies If I haven't), you want to extend the navigation background image to be behind the status bar too.

You can try this code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

in order for the nav_bar.png image to be behind the status bar too, you need to add 20px to the height of the image. The height of the Nav Bar is 44px.

Basically, nav_bar.png needs to be a width of 320px and ad height of 64px. It will then be behind the status bar.

I would advise that with iOS 7, you don't use flashy graphics (as Yanchi said) and just use a simple colour. Either choose the white or black default ones, or use the following code to change the colour tint of the Nav Bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor #Choose a colour#];
```

You replace #Choose a colour# with a UIColor such as blueColor or redColor.
You can also programmatically set the translucency to YES.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

To answer your last question about whether you can make the Nav Bar translucent, like Yanchi said, you'll only be able to change the actual image's alpha. If you want the blur effect (iOS 7 style) it doesn't work. I've tried and there doesn't seem to be a way. It only works with solid colours (using the UIColor code I mentioned).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Best     Article:

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your background image as a `UIColor`(sometimes you do need it) for any reasons:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"]]];
```